# PHP: Accessing Slim $response object

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to set the $response body within a PHP API as follows:

```
        $content = $this->getPDFService()->createPDF();
        $response = $this->app->response->header( 'Content-type', 'application/pdf' )->setBody($content);
```

However it allows me to set the header but not the body:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setBody() on string in /var/www/html/App/Controllers/Users.php:1429
```

perhaps I am missing a layer of abstraction within the call to `$this->app->response` I have tried setting the body such as `$response = $response->setBody($content);` but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Slim framework documentation at https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html, it appears you are not setting the header or content correctly.
To set a header

```
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withAddedHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
```

To set the content to a PDF file

```
$newStream = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\LazyOpenStream('/path/to/file', 'r');
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withBody($newStream);
```